# Need clarification: is it correct to return an array from a stateless component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

The docs say that you can return array from `render` method, but don't mention sfc. Also typescript typing doesn't allow that

However it works perfectly.

Is this a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anything that can be returned from `render` should be equally possible to return from a stateless function. Stateless functions are essentially "just the `render` method" in terms of usage.

The fact that Typescript typing doesn't support it could just be that it didn't fully adjust to React 16 release.

Comment: That's what I thought, but the typings mismatch confused me. I've just checked flow types and there returning array from stateless components is fine

Thanks for clarification